# Obtaining expression for recursive sequence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Can someone suggest how to obtain an expression for $S[i]$ given that S[0] = 0,

$S[i]=S[i-1]*(1-\gamma_i)^2 + \gamma_i^2$ where $\gamma_i = \frac{g+1}{g+i}$

EDIT: $g>0$ and $g$ can be assumed to be a natural number.

An exact expression or a lower bound would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I can show an upper bound of $s_i < i/gamma_i^2$

Comment: Assuming $g$>0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to determine a formula for this based off of looking at the first few elements of the sequence.

I have that $$s_i=\gamma_i^2(\sum_{n=1}^{i-1}(\prod _{k=n}^{i-1}\frac{k^2}{(g+k)^2})+1).$$

Now let’s look at bounding it from below. From your hunch that there is a $c$ such that $(g+i)s_i>c$, we proceed by finding which $c$ might give us an induction argument.

Suppose $(g+i)s_i>c$ for $i>0$. Then $$(g+i+1)s_{i+1}=\frac{i^2 s_i}{(g+i+1)}+\frac{(g+1)^2}{g+i+1} > \frac{i^2 c+(g+1)^2}{(g+i+1)^2}.$$

If we find a $c$ such that the final expression of the previous paragraph is greater than $c$ for all $i>0$, then we have the desired result. After some algebra and working backwards, it can be shown that any $c<(g+1)/2$ satisfies it. Following through with the induction argument, we can see that the base case ($i=1$) is satisfied since $s_1>1/2$.

Comment: Thanks! Can we simplify this further to get a lower bound? In particular, can we bound $\sum_{n=1}^{i-1} \Pi_{k=n}^{i-1}\frac{k^2}{(g+k)^2} \geq c i$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: What are we using this lower bound for? I believe that the limit as $i$ goes to infinity of $s_i$ is 0.

Comment: If any lower bound will do, then 0 is a lower bound.

Comment: Yes! I also believe that  $S[i]$ goes to $0$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ but I think $S[i] > c/(g+i)$ (i.e, a lower bound which depends on i). I tried coding it up and $S[i]*(g+i)$ seems to converge to a constant. I don't know how to prove it though.

Answer (score 1):

For a sequence $(S_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ generated as $S_i=a_iS_{i-1}+b_i$ with $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb R$, by recursively expanding once ore twice you can easily obtain a general formula.
$$\begin{align}
S_i
{}={} &
a_iS_{i-1}+b_i
\\
{}={} &
a_i(a_{i-1}S_{i-2}+b_{i-1})+b_i
\\
& {}\vdots{}
\\
{}={} &
a_ia_{i-1}\cdots a_1 S_0
{}+{}
b_i+a_ib_{i-1}+a_ia_{i-1}b_{i-2}+\ldots+ a_ia_{i-2}\cdots a_2b_1
\\
{}={} &
S_0\prod_{j=1}^ia_j
{}+{}
\sum_{j=1}^ib_j\prod_{k=j+1}^ia_k.
\end{align}$$
In your case $S_0=0$, hence the first term above vanishes.
What you need is a way to compute the remaining products and sums.

Since
$
a_k
{}={}
\left(1-\frac{g+1}{g+k}\right)^2
{}={}
\frac{(k-1)^2}{(g+k)^2}
$
and
$b_j=\frac{(g+1)^2}{(g+j)^2}$, you have
$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{b_j}\prod_{k=j+1}^ia_k
{}={} &
\color{red}{\frac{(g+1)^2}{(g+j)^2}}
\,\,
\frac{j^2}{(g+j+1)^2}
\frac{(j+1)^2}{(g+j+2)^2}
{}\cdots{}
\frac{(i-2)^2}{(g+i-1)^2}
\frac{(i-1)^2}{(g+i)^2}
\\
{}={} &
\color{red}{\frac{(g+1)^2}{(g+j)^2}}
\,\,
\frac{(i-1)!^2}{(j-1)!^2}
\frac{(g+j)!^2}{(g+i)!^2}
\\
{}={} &
(g+1)^2
\frac{(i-1)!^2}{(j-1)!^2}
\frac{(g+j-1)!^2}{(g+i)!^2},
\end{align}$$
where for simplicity $g$ was assumed natural.
The general case can easily be adapted by redefining the factorial accordingly (that is, $g!:=g$ and $(x+1)!:=(x+1)x!$, defined for $x\in g+\mathbb N$).

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
S_i
{}={} &
\frac{(g+1)^2(i-1)!^2}{(g+i)!^2}
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}
\frac{(g+j)!^2}{j!^2}
\\
\tag{1}
\mbox{(EDIT)}\quad
{}={} &
\frac{1}{\binom{g+i}{i-1}^2}
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}
\binom{g+j}{j}^2.
\end{align}$$
Now, in order to obtain a lower bound, notice that
$$
\binom{g+j}{j}
{}={}
\binom{g+j-1}{j-1}\frac{g+j}{j}
{}\geq{}
\binom{g+j-1}{j-1}\left(\textstyle 1+\frac{g}{i-1}\right)
\quad
\mbox{for }j\leq i-1
$$
therefore,
$$
\binom{g+j}{j}^2
{}\geq{}
\binom{g}{0}^2\left(\textstyle 1+\frac{g}{i-1}\right)^{2j}
{}={}
\left(\textstyle 1+\frac{g}{i-1}\right)^{2j},
$$
and plugging this into (1) yields
$$\begin{align}
S_i
{}\geq{} &
\frac{1}{\binom{g+i}{i-1}^2}
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}
\left(\textstyle 1+\frac{g}{i-1}\right)^{2j}
{}={}
\frac{1}{\binom{g+i}{i-1}^2}
\frac{(1+\frac{g}{i-1})^{2i}-1}{(1+\frac{g}{i-1})^2-1}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would it be possible to get something like $S_i(g+i) \geq c $ from here, where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: I added a lower bound, I don't know if that's what you need though